# After adding watch extension, app no longer runs

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, xcode-6.2

I created a watch extension/app that runs under the simulator.

When I try and run on the phone, Xcode says the app is running on the phone then after a few seconds it says finished running. 
No error, nothing.
 The app never runs on the iPhone.

Comment: You need to give us some more details. Anything relevant in the console? Have you tried setting an exception breakpoint? Any provisioning errors? What steps have you taken to try and solve the issue? There could be 100 answers to the question as you've currently written it.

Comment: I bet you have the wrong target selected at the top of Xcode by the run button

Comment: I feel certain it's some type of provisioning error, but Xcode says nothing. The Run target is the app, not the watch extension. I've created provisioning profiles for the app, for the watch app and the extension. The entitlements look correct (just the sharing domain). At least if there was an error shown I could have something to work with.

Comment: It was a provisioning error but my development certificate was always ok. I had to create a new one. Very frustrating. Hope you guys don't have to go through this.